# image classification Model, will all images get trained based on selected node hours?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have a single dataset for image classification, deployed to a single endpoint.  In the dataset there are currently about 2000 images, across 30 labels.  It will grow to over 100 labels, and 1.5x-2x images.

To keep costs down, I usually train 8 hour increments, using the Incremental training option each time I run a new model. I am using the default ML.

Is 8 hours enough to run through all the images properly?

When I view the Confusion matrix, there are only 11 labels listed.  Is this expected based on limited 8 hours?

Comment: Could you please check this [Link](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/AI-ML/Time-to-train-a-new-model-in-Vertex-AI/m-p/613993) ? Let me know if this is helpful or not.

Comment: thanks @ArpitaShrivastava, that is not quite what I was looking for.  I am wondering how do I know if 8 node hours across 1 machine will train across all labels?

Comment: Does this [Link](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/pricing) will help you ?